# Python Flask: Highcharts path allocation

Tags: jquery, python, html, highcharts, flask

I have a Highcharts on my website and it works fine when I use it on any random path/site, like e.g. `www.website.com/chart2.html`  with route --> `@app.route("/chart2/")`. But when I want to place it on my index.html `@app.route("/")`it doesn't work.

It has something to do with the path of the script `graph.js`, but I don't know what. I am calling `graph.js` in `chart2.html` like this and it works:

```
<script src="../static/js/graph.js"></script>
```

But if I call it in the `index.html` like mentioned below, it doesn't work:

```
<script src="static/js/graph.js"></script>
```

The browser console also tells me that in `graph.js` is an error, but like I said it works fine if I put the charts e.g. on website.com/chart2.html:

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function (--> graph.js:2:5)
>
> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).highcharts is not a function
>   @http://examplepage.com/static/js/graph.js:2:5 (--> jquery-...:2:31515)

This is the code from `graph.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(chart_id).highcharts({
        chart: chart,
        title: title,
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        series: series
    });
});
```

Does anybody has a clue whats happening here? If you need some more code, please let me know. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. 
I am using a bootstrap theme and at the bottom of it was a `jquery script tag`:

```
<script src="static/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

After I removed it, everything works fine!

The problem is, that I put a newer `jquery script tag` into the index.html in order to embed Highcharts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So I guess both script tags competed with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use static links. use the **url_for()** function.

#### Example Code

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/graph.js') }}"></script>
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your method works on every page, except on the homepath :-/